# JSON extend without overwriting attributes with same name

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, extend

I need to extend my JSON data. Now I have two objects:

```
const obj1 = {
   "data": [
      {
         "fruit num": 1,
         "kind": "sweet"
      },
      {
         "fruit num": 2,
         "kind": "sour"
      }
   ]
}

const obj2 = {
   "data": [
      {
         "fruit num": 3,
         "kind": "bitter"
      },
      {
         "fruit num": 4,
         "kind": "bitter"
      }
   ]
}
```

What I need to do is to make an obj3 file which would look like this:

```
const obj3 = {
   "data": [
      {
         "fruit num": 1,
         "kind": "sweet"
      },
      {
         "fruit num": 2,
         "kind": "sour"
      },
      {
         "fruit num": 3,
         "kind": "bitter"
      },
      {
         "fruit num": 4,
         "kind": "bitter"
      }
   ]
}
```

When I try to use *obj3 = obj1.concat(obj2)* - it says there is no such function.

When I try to use *obj3 = Object.assign(obj1, obj2)* - it overwrites the JSON file and then there are only 2 fruits left.

When I try to use *obj3.data = Object.assign(obj1.data, obj2.data)* - it does not change anything.

And yes, the {data:[]} is a must here.

How can I extend the JSON object without overwriting it?

P.S. I am using Node 8 here.

Comment: The simplest (if not the least verbose) way would be to just take the items from obj2.data and add them to the array of obj1.data, using a loop

Comment: `const obj3 = { data: obj1.data.concat(obj2.data) };`

Comment: @VicJordan I did not find the answer I was looking for in that article. Sorry.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you, this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly combine the `data` arrays to do that:

```
const obj3 = { data: [...obj1.data, ...obj2.data] };
```

If there are other properties in the two objects that you also want to combine into `obj3`, then you can `Object.assign` and pass a third object made up of the combined `data`:

```
const obj3 = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2, { data: [...obj1.data, ...obj2.data] });
```

Or, more concisely, with object spread:

```
const obj3 = {
  ...obj1,
  ...obj2,
  data: [...obj1.data, ...obj2.data]
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `concat` doesn't work because neither `obj1` nor `obj2` are arrays. You need to do it with `data` like so:

```
const obj3 = {
    data: obj1.data.concat(obj2.data)
}
```